# Running Azure AZ login command with Terraform

Tags: bash, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Issue:
I am trying to execute a bash script in Terraform and its throwing an error

Environment: I am running Terraform in VScode (terminal is bash) on Windows 10.
I've also tried running in standard git bash command terminal and it throws same error.
I've also tried replacing 'program = ["bash",' with 'program = ["az",' but still throws error.

my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit if any of the intermediate steps fail
set -e

# Login
az login --service-principal -u "${ARM_CLIENT_ID}" -p "${ARM_CLIENT_SECRET}" --tenant "${ARM_TENANT_ID}" >/dev/null

# Extract the query json into variables
eval "$(jq -r '@sh "SUBSCRIPTION_NAME=\(.subscription_name)"')"

# Get the subscription id and pass back map
az account list --query "[?name == '${SUBSCRIPTION_NAME}'].id | {id: join(', ', @)}" --output json
```

my main.tf file

```
locals {
    access_levels     = ["read", "write"]
    subscription_name = lower(var.subscription_name)
}

# lookup existing subscription
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

# Lookup Subscription
data "external" "lookupByName" {
  # Looks up a subscription by its display name and returns id
  program = ["bash", "${path.module}/scripts/lookupByName.sh"]

  query = {
    subscription_name = local.subscription_name
  }
}
```

throws error after running 'terraform plan'

```
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.external.lookupByName: Refreshing state...
data.azurerm_subscription.current: Refreshing state...

Error: failed to execute "bash": usage: az login [-h] [--verbose] [--debug] [--only-show-errors]
                [--output {json,jsonc,yaml,yamlc,table,tsv,none}]
                [--query JMESPATH] [--username USERNAME] [--password PASSWORD]
                [--service-principal] [--tenant TENANT]
                [--allow-no-subscriptions] [-i] [--use-device-code]
                [--use-cert-sn-issuer]
az login: error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)


  on main.tf line 10, in data "external" "lookupByName":
  10: data "external" "lookupByName" {
```

Comment: You need to make sure these three variables are passed thru correctly : `ARM_CLIENT_ID/ARM_CLIENT_SECRET/ARM_TENANT_ID`

Comment: @Philippe How do I do that without hardcoding the ARM_CLIENT_SECRET as a variable? Because I couldn't find any code examples or documentation on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) in Windows 10. From your commend, without hardcoding the ARM_CLIENT_SECRET as a variable, you can store the credentials as Environment Variables in WSL like this:

```
$ export ARM_CLIENT_ID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
$ export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
$ export ARM_TENANT_ID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

You could read [Configuring the Service Principal in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/service_principal_client_secret.html#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform) for more details.

However, the environment variable is temporarily valid in the current session in this way. If you want to permanently store its value, you can use a share `WSLENV` environment variables between Windows and WSL. Starting in 17063, `WSLENV` begins being supported. WSLENV is case sensitive.

For example,

Firstly, you could set the environment variables in Windows 10,

[image]

Secondly, set the `WSLENV` variable in the CMD.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>setx WSLENV ARM_TENANT_ID/u:ARM_CLIENT_ID/u:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET/u

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

Thirdly, re-start your VS code, you could check the current WSL environment variable with `export`.

[image]

At last, you should run `terraform plan` without such error in WSL in VScode.

For more information, you could refer to the following document,

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction! You are a lifesaver! :)

Comment: I am using Windows Terminal with PWSH 7 so I used: `$env:ARM_CLIENT_ID="$($client_id)"` instead of `export` because I was getting error `export: The term 'export' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program`.